# How can I add and remove list of select box in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, reactjs

1.I can only add and remove "value". It's doesn't remove from `UI`, but I see value "Add and Remove".  I need to value remove from `UI` that is label.

2. If user click one items list of selected box , it will add data inside `handleadd()` method. I don't need duplicate data .

3.if user click on Right arrow button , data will remove from select box(1) and it will add select box (2).

4.if user click on left arrow button , data will remove from select box(2) and it will add select box (1).

```
class FieldForm extends React.Component {

  state = {
    itemlist:[],
    itemlist2:[]
  }
  onChange = e => {
    const newitems = [...this.state.itemlist]
    newitems.push(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      itemlist:newitems
    });
  };


  handleadd = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      itemlist2:data
    })

  }
  handleremove= (data) => {
     console.log("remove",data)
    const newitems = [...this.state.itemlist2]

    newitems.pop(data);
    this.setState({
      itemlist2:data
    })
    console.log("data",data)
  }


  render() {

    const options = [

  {label:'Two', id:"2"
  },
 { label:'Three', id:"3"
}
,
{label:'Four', id:"4"
}]
    return (

    <select className="custom-select" onChange={this.onChange} multiple>
      {options&& options.map(item=>(  <option value={item.label}>{item.label}</option>))}

    </select>
    <div className="col-md-2 ">      
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleadd(this.state.itemlist)} class="btn btn-primary btn-block w-25 margin-bottom">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </button>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleremove(this.state.itemlist) }class="btn btn-primary btn-block w-25">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
    </button>
    </div>

    <select className="custom-select" multiple>
      {
        this.state.itemlist2.map(item=>( <option value={item}>{item}</option>))
      }
    </select>
    )
  }
}
```

How can solve this?

Comment: I'm having difficulties in understanding your requirement. I'll recite what I understood. Please correct If I'm wrong. You have to select list. On list item select and click on a button, You want the item to be moved to the other list. Is that right ?

Comment: yes , your are absolutely right

Comment: What are the two buttons for ?

Comment: when right arrow click, first select box data will move to second  and first is empty. when left arrow click, second select box data will move to first select. second is empty

Comment: On a single click, you want all the items in a box to be moved to the other?

Comment: yes , one is remove and other is add , it's like drag and drop

Comment: Do you want all 3 options to move on one click? Seems like you would want one at a time.

Comment: can you see your solution , when i click on item "three" after adding "first" value, it doesn't work properly

Comment: I need both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very DRY but here's a very thorough solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-mestorf-gpzx5

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class FieldForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    itemlist: [
      { label: "Two", id: "2", enabled: true },
      { label: "Three", id: "3", enabled: true },
      { label: "Four", id: "4", enabled: true }
    ],
    itemlist2: [],
    itemsToBeRemovedFromList1: [],
    itemsToBeRemovedFromList2: []
  };

  onChangeItemList1 = e => {
    const { itemlist, itemsToBeRemovedFromList1 } = this.state;
    const foundItem = itemlist.find(item => item.label == e.target.value);

    let allItems = [...itemsToBeRemovedFromList1, foundItem];

    //add item to the to be removed list
    this.setState({
      itemsToBeRemovedFromList1: [...allItems]
    });
  };

  onChangeItemList2 = e => {
    const { itemlist2, itemsToBeRemovedFromList2 } = this.state;
    const foundItem = itemlist2.find(item => item.label == e.target.value);

    //check for duplicates
    let allItems = [...itemsToBeRemovedFromList2, foundItem];

    //add item to the to be removed list
    this.setState({
      itemsToBeRemovedFromList2: [...allItems]
    });
  };

  handleadd = () => {
    const { itemlist, itemsToBeRemovedFromList1, itemlist2 } = this.state;
    const idsOfToBeRemovedItems = itemsToBeRemovedFromList1.map(
      item => item.id
    );
    const newItemList1 = itemlist.filter(
      item => !idsOfToBeRemovedItems.includes(item.id)
    );

    const newItemList2 = itemlist.filter(item =>
      idsOfToBeRemovedItems.includes(item.id)
    );

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      itemlist: newItemList1,
      itemlist2: [...itemlist2, ...newItemList2],
      itemsToBeRemovedFromList1: []
    });
  };

  handleremove = () => {
    const { itemlist, itemsToBeRemovedFromList2, itemlist2 } = this.state;
    const idsOfToBeRemovedItems = itemsToBeRemovedFromList2.map(
      item => item.id
    );
    const newItemList2 = itemlist2.filter(
      item => !idsOfToBeRemovedItems.includes(item.id)
    );

    const newItemList1 = itemlist2.filter(item =>
      idsOfToBeRemovedItems.includes(item.id)
    );

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      itemlist: [...itemlist, ...newItemList1],
      itemlist2: newItemList2,
      itemsToBeRemovedFromList2: []
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { itemlist, itemlist2 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          className="custom-select"
          onChange={this.onChangeItemList1}
          multiple
        >
          {itemlist &&
            itemlist.map(item => (
              <option id={item.id} value={item.label}>
                {item.label}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>

        <select
          className="custom-select"
          onChange={this.onChangeItemList2}
          multiple
        >
          {itemlist2 &&
            itemlist2.map(item => (
              <option id={item.id} value={item.label}>
                {item.label}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <div className="col-md-2 ">
          <button
            onClick={this.handleadd}
            class="btn btn-primary btn-block w-25 margin-bottom"
          >
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" />
            Add
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={this.handleremove}
            class="btn btn-primary btn-block w-25"
          >
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" />
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<FieldForm />, rootElement);
```

Comment: can you check , when I select 2 times , select don't move on right and also got label undefined error

Comment: Hmm its unclear how you want the items to move. Do you want all 3 items to move on one click? Or do you want to remove one at a time?

Comment: I want 3 items to move on one click and also get one item one click  Add and remove

Comment: can you fix its